# How to fix DTO file serialization error with new fields added?

Tags: serialization, dto

Error on DTO file for Serializing field

I have TestDTO.cs file inside this file, i have 5 field added as string and serialized that field. then one method created that method getting the called this DTO values. i have now new requirement is added more three fieled in that TestDTO.cs. But now if i add the fields in my class file. i am getting getting error as below:

```
Error in line 1 position 276. 'Element' 'additionalLimitAmountField' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ACE.Claims.HFC.ACC.Types.Policy' is not expected. Expecting element '_x003C_ClassTest_x003E_k__BackingField'.
```

can someone facing this type of issue in the code. so anyone can provide help, tell me how to get one.

we have tried nullble the value. it will not worked.